# Can't sort custom post type by random

Tags: wp-query, query

Here are the arguments for my query.

The query always shows the same order after every refresh.

Explanation to the query: 
it show only 4 posts of the custom post type `projekte`. The post has a custom meta field called `ecpt_skills` and it should check if there is a string in it which is stored in the variable `$porjektart`. It also should not show the current post. And it should order the query by random. Everything works except the random.

```
 $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 4,  
'post_type' => 'projekte', 
'meta_key'  => 'ecpt_skills', 
'meta_value' => $projektart, 
'meta_compare' => 'LIKE', 
post__not_in => array(get_the_ID()),
'orderby'=> 'rand' );
```

Does somebody know why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `meta_query` to search in the meta data, and then sort them as random:

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 4,  
        'post_type' => 'projekte', 
        'orderby'=> 'rand',
        'post__not_in' => array( get_the_ID() ),
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'ecpt_skills',
                'value' => $projektart,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            )
        ),
    );
```

There is also a mistype in your code, the post__not_in should be written as `'post__not_in'`.

And also, if your meta value is not numeric, you should use `meta_value` instead of `meta_value_num`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But still it always shows the same order.

Comment: @mhmma Although you have found the solution, but I've updated the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

I use the **custom post type order** plugin.

So random order doesn't effect the query.

You have to insert `'ignore_custom_sort' => true,` into your custom query to get it to work.